# How to enable slow query log in MySQL Galera?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-replication, galera

I want to enable slow query logging in MySQL Galera.

In order to do so, I have enabled it through `my.cnf`:

```
log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Then, I tried to restart one server

```
sudo services mysql restart
```

The galera node fails to restart and writes to error.log:

> mysqld_safe WSREP: Failed to recover position:  2015-08-29 12:07:37
>   27805 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of
>   myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>   release. Please use the full name instead. 2015-08-29 12:07:37 27805
>   [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 2015-08-29 12:07:37 27805
>   [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists 2015-08-29 12:07:37 27805 ...

Once I remove the query logging from `my.cnf`, the server starts just fine and joins the cluster OK.

Is there a special procedure in enabling the query log in Galera? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Galera with MySQL 5.6, [log_slow_queries was removed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries).

Here is what the MySQL 5.6 Documentation says on that option

> The [--log-slow-queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) option was removed in MySQL 5.6.1 (along with the [log_slow_queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) system variable). Instead, use the [--slow_query_log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log) option to enable the slow query log and the [--slow_query_log_file=file_name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file) option to set the slow query log file name.

Make you place the correct options under `[mysqld]` group header and not under `[mysqld_safe]`